# Is the implementation of fmincon different in R2012a and R2014a?

Tags: matlab

on my PC, I use R2014a and my script runs fine. The simulation server of my university runs R2012a and there a get an error running my script.

Here is the error:

> Warning: The default trust-region-reflective algorithm does not solve
>   problems with the constraints you have specified. FMINCON will use the
>   active-set algorithm instead. For information on applicable
>   algorithms, see Choosing the Algorithm in the documentation.
>
> Error using svd Input to SVD must not contain NaN or Inf.
>
> Error in pinv (line 29)    [U,S,V] = svd(A,0);
>
> Error in qpsub (line 463)
>                       projSD = pinv(projH)*(-Zgf);
>
> Error in nlconst (line 619)
>           [SD,lambda,exitflagqp,outputqp,howqp,ACTIND] ...
>
> Error in fmincon (line 794)
>       [X,FVAL,LAMBDA,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,GRAD,HESSIAN]=...
>
> Error in simulation_coop (line 85)
>                       [q, fval] = fmincon(neg_aux_fun, q0, [], [], [], [], [], ub, @(q)constraints( q, a_t, b_t, W, p_cell_lin, ss_lin,
>   h_cell2bs(:,:,n),
>                       h_trans2bs(:,:,n), rate ),options);

With R2014a I get neither the warning nor the error. So do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is more of a how-to:

1. First of all, check that you run your scripts on exactly the same data. Different data (type, size, values) might yield different results.
2. Check the release notes of the Optimization Toolbox. If there were any significant changes in it between R2012a and R2014a, you'll find those mentioned in the one/several of the release notes of the toolbox for R2012b, R2013a, R2013b or R2014b versions. Here is the list: http://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/release-notes.html

**Later edit**

As you may see in the page linked above, R2012b changes the default algorithm for `fmincon`.

Comment: Thank you. by changing the default algorithm to interior-point like in R2014a it is working fine now!

Comment: @HansG. Glad that I could help.